# How to get emails that do & don't end with the desired domain?

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I have a list of emails on a file `emails.txt`, how can I get emails that end with `@gmail.com` , and emails that **DON'T** end with `@gmail.com` , in two different files, using GREP or something similar

For ex.

```
***emails.txt***
email_1@gmail.com
email_2@gmail.com
email_3@hotmail.com
email_4@example.com
```

I need two different outputs like:

```
***emails-gmail.txt***
email_1@gmail.com
email_2@gmail.com
```

and

```
***emails-other.txt***
email_3@hotmail.com
email_4@example.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the emails that contain 'gmail.com', do:

```
cat emails.txt  | grep @gmail.com
```

and to get the emails that DON'T contain 'gmail.com', do:

```
cat emails.txt  | grep -v @gmail.com
```

Comment: No need to `cat`, but otherwise +1

Comment: What I mean is that `cat emails.txt | grep @gmail.com` is exactly the same as `grep @gmail.com emails.txt`

Comment: This is not how to do it. Try that when your input contains `bob@gmailscom.net`.

Comment: Indeed @EdMorton, but for all intents and purposes, OP is on a learning curve here, i'm sure that'll be their next stop.

Answer (score 1):

> THIS DOES **NOT** WORK!!

You can do it with `grep` only and then redirect STDOUT to file like this:

- Mails from `@gmail.com`:

  ```
  grep @gmail.com emails.txt > emails-gmail.txt
  ```
- Mails **not** from `@gmail.com`:

  ```
  grep -v @gmail.com emails.txt > emails-other.txt
  ```

  What `-v` does is it returns lines that **do not** contain `@gmail.com`.

---

> The above solution didn't work as expected, because `grep` uses regex and in regex, a *dot* `.` means match any character. We can use substitute `grep` for `fgrep` or `grep -F` that take argument as literal string instead of as regex! Then it works as intended. Additionally you can escape the regex dot with `\.`. Then you can again do

```
grep @gmail\.com emails.txt > emails-gmail.txt
```

Comment: This is not how to do it. Try that when your input contains `bob@gmailscom.net`.

Comment: Indeed, well spotted. Editting

Comment: You also need to add the end of string (which is also end of line in this case) anchor `$` so `bob@gmail.company.org` doesn't match: `grep '@gmail\.com$' file`.

Answer (score 1):

The right approach is:

```
awk '{print > ("emails-" (/@gmail\.com$/ ? "gmail" : "other") ".txt")}' emails.txt
```

That will parse your input file once, generating both output files as it goes, and will  correctly handle the potential false matches that the other solutions posted so far would fail on.